# Python Sorting lists by value

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

Lets say I have a list of players

```
listOfPlayers = [
                 ("Player1","PG",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player2","PG",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player3","SG",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player4","SG",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player5","SF",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player6","SF",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player7","PF",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player8","PF",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player9","C",Cost,projectedPoints),
                 ("Player10","C",Cost,projectedPoints) 
                ]
```

Then an empty list

```
selectedList = []
```

I need to sort through the players by position and pull out the best cost/projected points ratio into the selected list, but the catch is i can only have 1 of each position, such as (pg, sg, sf, pf, c). How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort by the cost/projected points ratio:

```
listOfPlayers.sort(key=lambda (name, pos, cost, pts): float(cost)/pts, reverse=True)
```

Then loop through the list and pull them out:

```
results = {}
for name, pos, cost, pts in listOfPlayers:
    if pos in results:
        #position already filled
        continue 
    results[pos] = (name, pos, cost, pts)
```

You might want to stop earlier depending on whether you know what positions you'll need in advance, e.g.:

```
needed_positions = set(["PG", "SG", "SF", "C"])
results = {}
for name, pos, cost, pts in listOfPlayers:
    if not needed_positions:
        #all spots filled
        break
    if pos in results:
        #this position already filled
        continue 
    results[pos] = (name, pos, cost, pts)
    needed_positions.remove(pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
players.sort(operator.itemgetter(1)) # sort by position
for pos, players in itertools.groupby(players, key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
  best = max(players, key=lambda p:float(p[2])/p[3])
  print "The best player for position %s is %s" %(best[1], best[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

players = [
    # name          position    cost    projected_points
    ("Player1",     "PG",       1,      13),
    ("Player2",     "PG",       2,      54),
    ("Player3",     "SG",       4,      44),
    ("Player4",     "SG",       8,      34),
    ("Player5",     "SF",       3,      14),
    ("Player6",     "SF",       2,      91),
    ("Player7",     "PF",       10,     20),
    ("Player8",     "PF",       4,      32),
    ("Player9",     "C",        9,      12),
    ("Player10",    "C",        3,      82)
]

def cost(p):
    return float(p[3]) / p[2]

players.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: (x[1], cost(x)))

for k, g in itertools.groupby(players, lambda x: x[1]):
    best = list(g)[0]
    print(best)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in doing this with a [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html) object, this code would work. This is helpful if you end up needing to perform these kinds of sorting / aggregating actions often or on larger data -- and it uses efficient NumPy array operations to perform calculations quickly.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(listOfPlayers, 
                      columns=["Player", "Pos", "Cost", "ProjectedPoints"])

df['Ratio'] = df.Cost / df.ProjectedPoints
best_players = df.groupby("Pos").apply(lambda x: x.Player.values[x.Ratio.argmax()])
```